# UITableView is not updated from plist

Tags: uitableview, plist

Please,
I have a Master table view and Detail View and I have a plist with some information.
When I run the App, my master view will get the items in a Plist and viewed, After that When i click on a button Add: +
then redirect to Detail View controller that have a register form,I write all the information and then click on a  save button it.
My current view become the Master view that is not updated with the new information that i ADDED in my Detail View. so please what must i check and how can i fix this issue ?

Regards
A.J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have in viewWillAppear method for your master controller code [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Thanks sir for your feedback, Yes i have the following : -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
    [self viewDidLoad];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
   } but it is still not working.

Comment: My master table is still get the old information from the Plist, on my Detail view i tried to print the new plist that have a new items , and it is working fine, but How can i make my Master view  updated with the new items. please Help!!!

Comment: Now, I added the following code to my save method:   NSString * plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Profile" ofType:@"plist"]; and i could update my Master view controller, but when i close the App, i don't get the new items on my Master view controller. Please Help!!!

Comment: how you saved your data to that plist? Try to use this: NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/Profile.plist", NSHomeDirectory()]; After that you can save your data with: [yourArrayContainingData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

Comment: WOW,You are sooooooo clever. Thank you so much, I am very happy.Please can do tell me where is the difference between your code and the following : plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Profile" ofType:@"plist"];

Comment: Try NSLog your plistPath.